# Android:Go to the next item on a List

Tags: android, listview, countdowntimer, onitemclick

I am fighting with my first app for Android: I have list of timers displayed (CountDowntTimer) in a List. When you tick(*onItemClick*) any of them the timer starts running. The timers work just fine, but when each timer ends I want to jump to the next element of the List and execute the next timer.

I don't know how to do this: Maybe I can call the onItemClick() method from the *onFinish* method of the CountDownTimer? I don't know how to do this with the correct arguments (AdapterView a, View v, int position, long id)

Is there any other way? Probably there is, but I don't know it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Here you have some code:

```
lstRepeticiones.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                if(!timerHasStarted){

                String opcionSeleccionada = 
                            ((Repeticion)a.getAdapter().getItem(position)).getTitulo();
                lblEtiqueta.setText("Opción seleccionada: " + opcionSeleccionada);

                countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer((Integer.parseInt(datos[position].getDuracion().toString()) *1000), 1000,a , v , position , id);
                countDownTimer.start();
                timerHasStarted = true;
            }
            else{
                lblEtiqueta.setText("Elija opción");
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                timerHasStarted = false;
            }
```

There you can see how on each onItemClick I write a *TextView* (a message on the screen) according to some data. And after that I start the corresponding timer for that selection, and represent the *CountDownTimer* on the screen in the place where that option is. If there is already a timer running, everything will stop.

The idea now is that, when the timer ends, I want to go on with the next item on the list.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, onItemClick is very convenient place to do this. But don't call onItemClick, just implement it in your activity class, to do that you need add this implements statement to your activity: `ActivityName implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adp, View view, int position, long id) {
    // Do whatever you want for the current view here
    // You want to start the timer here, you can also keep a global variable of this and call it currentlyRunningTimer.
    // at onFinish method, you can start another timer

   // The next view is at position + 1, listView is a variable for your ListView
   View nextItem = listView.getChildAt(position+1);

   if(nextItem != null){
      // Do whatever you want here, for the next item.
      // you can access items in the next item like this
      TextView text = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.text);
   }

}
```

Comment: Ok, this could work. Lets see if I am able to code it. Ill do some tests and coment back. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Up to now, using _getChildAt()_ I have been able to check that I canmodify the different elements on the list. My problem now is that, when I do it from the _CountDownTimer.OnFinish()_ method, it always does the update of the view in the last of the elements of my list. I will go on with the tests.

Comment: Only the visible elements are created, hence listView only contains the visible elements, not all of the elements your adapter has. Take this into account, while modifying the listView items.

Comment: Right! Thats interesting. Another thing to take into account. It can explain why it always updates the last visible element. But I still don't know why it doesn't update the rest. Still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

For each item write code to start another timer in onFinish() method.

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         //Start another CountDownTimer
     }
  }.start();
```

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I want to show the countdown of the timer in the next item of the list. Thats the point where I have problems.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to call `onItemClick()` programatically, instead just call the code from `onItemClick()` directly. Anyway, it's not easy to give a good answer without seeing your code.